# OnDragListener Fires Several Times?

Tags: java, android

I have several layouts; each containing a `TextView`. If the user drags a `TextView` unto another `TextView`, I'm going to execute the method `swapFamily()` but **it fires several times, depending on the number of families**.

`FamilyItemLayout` is just a custom `LinearLayout` with a `String` attribute attached to it and with add'tl getters and setter for that attribute.

However, my issue is that,

```
private class onDropFamily implements View.OnDragListener {

    @Override
    public boolean onDrag(View view, DragEvent event) {

        TextView txtDragged = (TextView) event.getLocalState();
        TextView txtTarget = (TextView) view;
        String familyDragged = ((FamilyItemLayout) txtDragged.getParent()).getFamily();
        String familyTarget = ((FamilyItemLayout) txtTarget.getParent()).getFamily();

        switch (event.getAction()) {
            // Signals the start of a drag and drop operation.
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED:
                break;
            // Signals to a View that the drag point has entered the bounding box of the View.
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED:
                view.setBackgroundResource(R.mipmap.pill_sun);
                break;
            // Signals that the user has moved the drag shadow outside the bounding box of the View.
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED:
                view.setBackgroundResource(R.mipmap.pill_sky);
                break;
            // Signals to a View that the user has released the drag shadow, and the drag point is within the bounding box of the View.
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:
                break;
            // Signals to a View that the drag and drop operation has concluded.
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED:
                // Check if drag event was successful
                if (dropEventHandled(event)) {
                    fixedPlan.swapFamily(familyDragged, familyTarget);
                }
                txtDragged.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                txtTarget.setBackgroundResource(R.mipmap.pill_sky);
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }

    private boolean dropEventHandled(DragEvent dragEvent) {
        return dragEvent.getResult();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you should put those code in `ACTION_DROP` instead of ACTION_DRAG_ENDED

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/DragEvent.html

> All views that received an ACTION_DRAG_STARTED event will receive the
>   ACTION_DRAG_ENDED event even if they are not currently visible when
>   the drag ends.

Also remember to return correct value for `ACTION_DROP`

> The View should return true from its onDragEvent(DragEvent) handler or
>   OnDragListener.onDrag() listener if it accepted the drop, and false if
>   it ignored the drop.

Comment: Thank you so much. I was freaking out. I should've read the documentation more thoroughly.